# Im trying to make a program that just displays the tiles 2 players would start with in Scrabble, but it keeps crashing?

Tags: c++, crash

I have this program I am working on that is similar to scrabble. This program below is a "mini-program" however, it should just be able to print out the 7 starting tiles for the two players. This mini-program seems like it should be fully operational, but it just crashes. Do you guys have an ideas as to why it doesnt run. Thanks so much for your time! :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void selectTiles(char (*lettArray)[53], char (*playPieces)[8], char (*compPieces)[8])
{
    int pP1, pP2, pP3, pP4, pP5, pP6, pP7;
    int cP1, cP2, cP3, cP4, cP5, cP6, cP7;
    //0000000

    srand(time(NULL)); 
    rand();

    pP1=rand()%53;
    (*playPieces)[0]=(*lettArray)[pP1];
    strcpy((lettArray)[pP1],"*");

    do{
        pP2=rand()%53;
        (*playPieces)[1]=(*lettArray)[pP2];

    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP2],"*")==0);

    do{
        pP3=rand()%53;
        (*playPieces)[2]=(*lettArray)[pP3];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP3],"*")==0);

    do{
         pP4=rand()%53;(*playPieces)[3]=(*lettArray)[pP4];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP4],"*")==0);

    do{
         pP5=rand()%53;(*playPieces)[4]=(*lettArray)[pP5];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP5],"*")==0);

    do{
         pP6=rand()%53;(*playPieces)[5]=(*lettArray)[pP6];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP6],"*")==0);

    do{
         pP7=rand()%53;(*playPieces)[6]=(*lettArray)[pP7];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[pP7],"*")==0);

    do{
         cP1=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[0]=(*lettArray)[cP1];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP1],"*")==0);

    do{
         cP2=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[1]=(*lettArray)[cP2];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP2],"*")==0);

    do{
         cP3=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[2]=(*lettArray)[cP3];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP3],"*")==0);

   do{
         cP4=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[3]=(*lettArray)[cP4];
   }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP4],"*")==0);

   do{
         cP5=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[4]=(*lettArray)[cP5];
   }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP5],"*")==0);

   do{
         cP6=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[5]=(*lettArray)[cP6];
   }while(strcmp((lettArray)[cP6],"*")==0);

   do{
         cP7=rand()%53;(*compPieces)[6]=(*lettArray)[cP7];
    }while(strcmp((lettArray)   [cP7],"*")==0);

    //0000000 

 }

int main()
{
    char lettArray[53]="AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ";
    char (*pLetters)[53]=&lettArray;

    char player[8];
    char (*pPlayer)[8]=&player;

    char computer[8];
    char (*pComputer)[8]=&computer;
    selectTiles(pLetters,pPlayer,pComputer); 

    for (int i=0;i<53;i++)
       cout<<"|"<<lettArray[i]<<"|";

     cout<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
       cout<<"|"<<player[i]<<"|";

     cout<<endl;


     for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        cout<<"|"<<computer[i]<<"|";

     cout<<endl;
     system("pause");
 }
```

Comment: I don't know which operation is causing undefined behavior, but I suspect that you could save yourself a lot of trouble by using `std::string` instead of `char []`, and references instead of pointers.

Comment: I am not allowed to used std::string

Comment: @Guitardeon: In that case, you've been asked to solve a problem with one hand (perhaps both hands!) tied behind your back. Experienced programmers use all the tools that they can to make a difficult job a bit easier, and the C++ standard library is one of the most important of those tools.

Comment: Yes but when an instructor say if you use anything not taught in class you will lose points, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
void selectTiles(char (*lettArray)[53], ...)
{
  ...
  pP1=rand()%53;
  strcpy((lettArray)[pP1],"*");
  ...
}
```

That `strcpy` is *not* doing what you think it's doing. It's (usually) writing out of bounds and causing undefined behavior. Use `std:string` instead of `char []`, references instead of pointers, and test your code as you develop it, and you won't have these problems.

**EDIT:**

All right, first let's tidy up the code so we can see what we're doing. All of those copy-and-pasted do-while loops in `selectTiles(...)` are painful to look at. Step 1, we introduce a new function for drawing a random character from `lettArray`:

```
char draw(char *lettArray)
{
  int pp;
  do{
    pp=rand()%53;
  }while(lettArray[pp]=='*');
  return(lettArray[pp]);
}

void selectTiles(char (*lettArray)[53], char (*playPieces)[8],
                 char (*compPieces)[8])
{
  int pP1;

  //0000000

  srand(time(NULL));
  rand();

  pP1=rand()%53;
  (*playPieces)[0]=(*lettArray)[pP1];
  strcpy((lettArray)[pP1],"*");

  (*playPieces)[1]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*playPieces)[2]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*playPieces)[3]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*playPieces)[4]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*playPieces)[5]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*playPieces)[6]=draw(*lettArray);

  (*compPieces)[0]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[1]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[2]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[3]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[4]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[5]=draw(*lettArray);
  (*compPieces)[6]=draw(*lettArray);

  //0000000

}
```

This alone reduces the length of the code by 30 lines and makes it much easier to read. It also underscores the silliness of passing *pointers to arrays*. In C an array is passed as a pointer to the first element, so no further indirection is necessary. And since (in `selectTiles`) `lettArray` is a pointer to a `char[]`, this line:

```
strcpy((lettArray)[pP1],"*");
```

is deadly. If `pP1` is, say, 12, you're not putting an asterisk at the twelfth (or thirteenth) position in the array, you're copying "*" into *the twelfth char array past the real one.* That is, you're writing out of bounds. Let's correct the line (and put in some `for` loops):

```
  pP1=rand()%53;
  (*playPieces)[0]=(*lettArray)[pP1];
  (*lettArray)[pP1]= '*';

  for(int k=1 ; k<7 ; ++k)
    (*playPieces)[k]=draw(*lettArray);

  for(int k=0 ; k<7 ; ++k)
    (*compPieces)[k]=draw(*lettArray);
```

And the code stops crashing. There's still a lot of improvement possible, but now it works.

Comment: Im not allowed to use std:string because we didnt talk about it in class

Comment: Thank you so much! What an insightful response. I really appreciate you taking time out of your day and helping me. I made a minor change so I could cross out a picked tile:        temp=lettArray[location];
  lettArray[location]='*';
  
  return(temp);                                                                and now everything works fine. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this program on g++ version 4.5.3 under Cygwin and, after changing `#include <string>` to `#include <cstring>` it compiled and ran without apparent problem.

However, when I looked at the output, it was clear that the program was writing 8 letters instead of 7 for each player's Scrabble letters and the last letter in each set was from a previously unallocated piece of memory.

Thus, I'd suggest the lines like:

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
```

... should be:

```
for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
```

There might well be other errors that I haven't spotted yet.

(EDIT)

The line:

for (int i=0;i<53;i++)

... also prints an extra character. It should be:

for (int i=0;i<52;i++)

Also, amplifying Beta's point on the use of `strcpy`, `strcpy(dest,"*")` will copy *two* characters to the address pointed to by `dest`, not one character. That is, it will copy "*" *and* the null that terminates the string. That will probably overwrite data that was not intended to be overwritten with the null.

Comment: Ok so it still crashes is though I change it to cstring. Good catch on the for-loops btw! Oh and since im using strcpy on a since element of the char array, wouldnt the "*" fill in the letter that was located in the spot, since it can only copy one element and not more than that?

Comment: Since you're copying one character at a time rather than a whole string, it seems to me (I'm not completely sure of your intended output) that you could just write `lettArray[pP1] = "*";`. Incidentally, you don't need most of the literal values for the dimensions of your arrays. Writing (for instance) `char lettArray[]="AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ";` is easier and more maintainable because it lets the compiler do the work of counting the number of characters in your array.

Comment: The problems with the `strcpy` are much worse than that.

Comment: If I use the line lettArray[pP1] = "*" in place of the strcpy, I get the error message: "incompatible types in assignment of `const char[2]' to `char[53]'" I would assume that it is because the "*" counts as two spots in an array because of the "*" character and the null. My intended output is just a print out of two player's tiles. I am making it so that once a tile is randomly selected from the 52 letters, to make sure the same letter is not chosen again I change that array location from the letter chosen to a "*". So a sample output would be AGRITHF and ORITNGF.

Comment: I also print out lettArray to ideally see the "*"'s in place of the 14 titles of the 52 selected